# Creating random positioned cracks on pre made model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, modifiers

I need to apply cracks on model. I've tried to use boolean with crack shaped objects on bigger object but renders take too much time. Also I need 500 renders. Any suggestions ? In the figure below crack is circled. Crack should be on the diffrent positions and diffrent rotations

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.